# using two hash tables to identify similarities in javascript

Tags: javascript, hash, hashmap, compare, hashtable

I am trying to use hash tables to compare my magazine array below with my notes array.  I look at the problem and see that it could be done in other ways but I am trying to specifically learn how to use hash tables.  I want to see if magazine has the same words within it as notes. My idea is to end up with something like this and then compare them

```
magazineHash = {
    "cool": 2,
    "needs": 1,
    "some": 1,
    "for": 1,
    "work": 1
}
```

and the same for notes array and then to compare the frequencies (values) of the words

```
magazine = ["cool", "needs", "some", "for", "work", "cool"];
notes = ["cool", "needs", "for", "cool", "work"]

function reliableNote(magazine, note){

}
```

There is so much info and variety in what people talk about regarding hash tables online, I am getting very confused!  Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to map an `array` to an `object/hash table` you could use the `reduce` function:

```js
const magazine = ["cool", "needs", "some", "for", "work", "cool"];
const notes = ["cool", "needs", "for", "cool", "work"]


function mapToHash(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((hash, entry) => ({ ...hash,
    [entry]: hash[entry] ? hash[entry] + 1 : 1
  }), {})
}

console.log(mapToHash(magazine));
console.log(mapToHash(notes));
```

Comment: awesome.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you